# Странное поведение Maven и Java

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, maven, windows-10

Всем доброго дня.
Пару дней назад появилась странная ошибка в Intelij IDEA:

**Software caused connection abort: recv failed**

Maven перестал подтягивать зависимости.
Сделал `mvn -X clean package`
Весь stackTrace приводить не буду только ошибки:

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake
>
> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake
>
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
>
> Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Окружение Windows 10 со всеми последними обновлениями.
Java version "1.8.0_172" .
Apache Maven 3.5.3
IntellijIDEA последняя версия.

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: А в браузере вы можете открыть https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 ?

Comment: Да, могу без проблем.

Comment: покажите ваш pom и settings.xml . P.S вы случайно не используете Spring Cloud Contract ? Была такая же проблема с этой либой.

Comment: Нет не использую. https://dropmefiles.com/zV0M3 (в архиве pom и settings)

Comment: Вся проблема была в настройках Sockets Windows. ПО сути к Maven никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Antony20
Приветствую, наблюдаем ту же ситуацию при переходе на Windows 10. Не совсем понятно, что конкретно не так с настройкой Sockets Windows, куда смотреть, что менять))
Очень помогло бы объяснение как вы решили эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже на то, что клиент и сервер не могут договориться о протоколе защищенного соединения. Попробуйте указать его явно:

```
 mvn -X clean package -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Также возможно, что какое-то стороннее программное обеспечение, к примеру антивирус, проксирует через себя ваше соединение при этом подменяя ваш удалённый адрес на себя и, как следствие, протокол соединения.

P.S. Подобная проблема описана на [xaбре](https://habr.com/ru/news/t/445462/).

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае проблема в том, что используется IPv6.
Нужно принудить JVM использовать IPv4 версию используя:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Такое обсуждалось в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765765/use-maven3-in-ipv4-network-but-throws-a-ipv6-throws-a-ipv6-exception/9766047